How to get output of ls command into make variable and use it later on?
I want to get the output of the following shell command into a make variable:
# The following is used as a path containing the following directories named:
# install-20240714, install-20240715, install-20240716.

# The directories are contained in ${DOWNLOAD_PATH}/${PROVIDER_NAME}.
# From this, the output of the command is the most recent numeric date 
# which I want to refer to, later on, in the same recipe.
 
DOWNLOAD_PATH=/tmp; \
PROVIDER_NAME=tug.org; \
pkgRelDate=`ls ${DOWNLOAD_PATH}/${PROVIDER_NAME} \
    | tail -n 1 \
    | awk '{match($0, /[0-9]{8}/, date); print date[0]}'`; \
cat ${TEMPLATE_NAME} > ${pkgRelDate}.pfl

TEMPLATE_NAME is a plain text file that needs to be outputed into ${pkgRelDate}.pfl.
I tried to echo the output of the ls command but the value of the variable seems empty.
What am I missing?

There's nothing wrong with make: it's your shell command that's wrong.  If you cut and paste that to the shell command line (replacing $$ with $) you'll see it prints nothing.  You should first write the command on the shell so you're sure it works, then you can add it to your makefile (replacing $ with $$).  I'm not even really sure what this script is trying to do.  Are you trying to do the equivalent of stat -c %f?

If you're trying to get the mod time as printed by ls, the very first thing you need to do is run ls -l not just ls.

Oh, maybe you have a specially formatted file here, but you just neglected to show us the filename so we can't reproduce the issue.  All I can say to that is, what you have here should work so whatever is wrong is something you haven't shown us.  If, for example, I use pkgRelDate = $(shell echo foobar) then expanding ${pkgRelDate} gives the value foobar as expected.

Separately, don't parse ls output

@MadScientist, I tried the command from Zsh, and it works as expected.  Thanks for your input about the $ sign.

Generally, putting your shell program into a separate script and calling that script from your makefile is a lot easier to deal with than embedding it in a makefile. Beyond that, using tail before awk is going to be troublesome if the last result doesn't match your pattern; it makes more sense to let awk itself do the work of finding the last file that matches your name (though you shouldn't be sourcing those filenames from ls in the first place for the reasons given in tripleee's link above).

(Separately, stay away from all-caps names for your own variables -- as specified in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, that's the namespace used for special variables, like PATH, that modify or reflect behavior of the shell and other POSIX-specified tools; in standard-compliant shells -- bash, ash, dash, sh, modern ksh, not zsh -- names with at least one lower-case character are guaranteed not to have unexpected side effects on the shell's behavior).

BTW, backslashes' behavior is modified inside backticks, but not inside modern $( ) command substitution syntax. (Though if you move the | characters from front-of-line to the end of the preceding line, then you don't need backslashes at all).

You've completely rewritten this example and now it is really broken.  If this is what you were using previously no wonder it didn't work :)  But, this version doesn't use a shell function at all so I'm confused.

Anyhow, the new code isn't written in a manner appropriate for direct inclusion in a makefile at all, and you don't show how it's being run (so we don't know if that's a problem or not). Make sure you're providing a [mre] -- everything needed to reproduce the problem and be certain that what we're seeing is the same problem (as opposed to a difference in test procedure or such). (You might also want to put set -x; at the front of the command so you get a trace log of execution and can use that to better inform the question).

I'm not really sure what you want to do because you haven't actually shown a complete rule, just a bunch of small snippets that can be combined in many ways in a makefile.  But, remember that the entirety of a recipe runs inside the shell.  So you can't set makefile variables from within a recipe: you can only set shell variables from within a recipe.  And when you reference shell variables in a recipe, you must always use $$ not $.
Here's a way to get what you want (based on the comments and examples in your question) using GNU Make functions, outside of any recipe:
# This all appears OUTSIDE of a make recipe and sets MAKE variables
DOWNLOAD_PATH = /tmp
PROVIDER_NAME = tug.org

pkgRelDate = $(patsubst install-%,%,$(lastword $(sort $(notdir $(wildcard ${DOWNLOAD_PATH}/${PROVIDER_NAME}/install-*)))))

# Now you can use this MAKE variable in a recipe
myrule:
        cat ${TEMPLATE_NAME} > ${pkgRelDate}.pfl

If you must perform this check inside a recipe (because, for example, the files you want to check in ${DOWNLOAD_PATH}/${PROVIDER_NAME} are created by the recipe where they are used) then you have to use shell commands:
myrule:
        <do stuff that generates the install-files>
        # This creates a SHELL variable in this recipe
        pkgRelDate=`cd /tmp/tug.org; ls -1  \
            | tail -n 1 \
            | sed 's/install-//'`; \
        cat ${TEMPLATE_NAME} > "$$pkgRelDate".pfl


I didn't wanted to include the whole rule.  Shall I rework it as a MWE?

If the answer here doesn't help you solve your problem then that is probably the next step.

Thank you all for the support.  I suggest the following solution taking all of your inputs into consideration.
Here's a MRE:
#!/usr/bin/env -S /usr/bin/make -f
# ##############################################################################

# How to store returned output of shell command into a variable from a make
# recipe to refer to it successively?

.ONESHELL:
install:
    mkdir -p ${DownloadPath}/${ProviderName}
    tar -C ${DownloadPath}/${ProviderName} -zxf ${DownloadPath}/${DistName}

    dirFind=$$(find ${DownloadPath}/${ProviderName} -name 'install-tl-*' -type d)
    for dirPath in $$(echo "$${dirFind}" | tac); do \
        cat ${CfgPath}/${TemplateName} > $${dirPath}/${PackageName}.pfl; \
        export TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${InstallPrefix} && \
            perl $${dirPath}/install-tl -profile $${dirPath}/${PackageName}.pfl; \
        break;
    done
.PHONY: install

